# lumen framework routing not working

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I use the Lumen framework for first time, the route `/` to my HomeController is not working.

This is my route.php:

```
$app->get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

But I get the following error:

```
[2015-04-17 07:03:41] lumen.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class HomeController does not exist' in /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:776

Stack trace:
#0 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(776): ReflectionClass->__construct('HomeController')
#1 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(656): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('HomeController', Array)
#2 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(358): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('HomeController', Array)
#3 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1184): Laravel\Lumen\Application->make('HomeController')
#4 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1157): Laravel\Lumen\Application->callControllerAction(Array)
#5 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1142): Laravel\Lumen\Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(Array)
#6 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1120): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleArrayBasedFoundRoute(Array)
#7 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1058): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleFoundRoute(Array)
#8 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(1006): Laravel\Lumen\Application->dispatch(NULL)
#9 /Users/refear99/Web/qingsongchou_api/public/index.php(28): Laravel\Lumen\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

This is my HomeController.php in /app/Http/Controllers/

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller {

public function index()
{
    echo 123;
}

}
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Do you have `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` in that controller file?

Comment: @lukasgeiter yes,  namespace App\Http\Controllers; in the HomeController.php

Comment: For your reference, This link has good tutorial about lumen installation and create new REST api http://wsnippets.com/create-rest-api-using-lumen-micro-framework-by-laravel/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to use the fully qualified classname:

```
$app->get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index');
```

**OR** wrap all routes in a group (which is actually how it's done under the hood in Laravel 5)

```
$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function($group){

    $group->get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    $group->get('foo', 'FooController@index');

});
```

Comment: This is strange, because if you look into https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/bootstrap/app.php#L97 there is already namespace option, but it does not work - hey wait it works but not in nested groups :(

Comment: The docs that say the exact opposite are mildly confusing. https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: @Helliax This answer was definitely correct when I wrote it (Lumen 5.0). It's very much possible that this has been changed in one of the newer releases. I don't have time to try it out right now, but if somebody can confirm that it actually changed, I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: @lukasgeiter you're answer is still correct. My comment was more in the line with skcin7. Doesn't make sense that the docs say the opposite of what actually works.

Comment: It seems that there is a typo.  $group should be $app otherwise $app will not be passed into the closure and $group will be an undefined variable. Other than that, works with a smile.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be undocumented right now, but you need to use the full namespace path to the controller.

So your route would look like this:

```
$app->get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index');
```

The difference lies in the RouteServiceProvider that ships with Laravel, which can be found in app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php, check out the map method, it looks as follows

```
$router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function($router)
{
    require app_path('Http/routes.php');
});
```

So all of your application routes are actually grouped under a default namespace, which is usually App\Http\Controllers.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the file `/bootstrap/app.php` There you can make some settings. Also there, at the bottom of the file, you will find the following lines.

```
$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/routes.php';
});

return $app;
```

Which should serve your calls with the right namespace.

Also you can activate the .env settings right there :)

Take a look at this Post https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-lumen-from-laravel

Hope this helps someone! :)