# Can't use $request in controller.index() with lumen / laravel (index should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::index )

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen

Using lumen 5.2, I am setting up a GET action that can have resource queries:

```
GET /expedientes?param1=value1&..paramn=valuen
```

In my routing I have:

```
$app->get('expedientes', 'ExpedientesController@index');
```

In my controller:

```
class ExpedientesController extends Controller

  public function index(Request $request){
    if ($request->has('name')) {
       return $request->input('name');
    }
  }
}
```

The error I obtain:

```
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\ExpedientesController::index(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::index
```

The funny thing is, if I rename the controler to a name different from "index", like "indexa" (in both the controller and the routing file) everything works perfectly.

So my question is: Using the standard function name "index" for getting a list of resources, which is the proper way to access the request?

Thanks a lot, regards,

---

Possible solution #1:

I found out that lumen doesn't use the same controllers as laravel ( [lumen: App\Http\Controllers\Controller class not found with fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871040/lumen-app-http-controllers-controller-class-not-found-with-fresh-install) ).

Using

```
use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
```

In the controller so it inherits from lumen's controller

```
class ExpedientesController extends BaseController
```

allows me to use a Request parameter in the index method.

But I wonder. Is this the proper way? Even if it is, what would be the way to do this in laravel?

Comment: What was your controller inheriting instead of`Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller` ?

Comment: I was inheriting from "Controller", as the Example controller was doing. There was a typo, sorry.